# MySQL - need to query from few columns

Tags: mysql

Please help me to write correct query for a few tables. I need to replace all id here from another table
[api json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CN2a.png)

I am trying to make query like this

```
SELECT incident.`number`, `user`.first_name, (SELECT `user`.first_name  from ITSM.`user` JOIN incident on `user`.sys_id = incident.id_created_by) as createdby
from ITSM.incident
JOIN ITSM.`user` on incident.id_caller = `user`.sys_id
;*
```

but it doesn#t work, I got an error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

How can i make a right query?

This one doesn't work also, same error:

```
SELECT incident.`number`, (SELECT user.first_name from ITSM.`user`, ITSM.incident WHERE user.sys_id = incident.id_created_by) as createdby
from ITSM.incident
JOIN ITSM.`user` on incident.id_caller = user.sys_id*
;
```

and this is my
[DB id for user who created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eDDM.png)

Comment: Please provide more details and be more precise of what you want to do. You are writing "i need to replace all id" but you are writing queries only. Do you want to replace sth or do you want to select sth? Could you please provide your data here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 or at least add the necessary SQL commands to create your data, thus your issue is reproducable? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post *images of text* - just post the text.  Posting a screen just shot limits how much help we can offer because we can't copy text and work up a query using your sample data from a screen shot.  See how to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery. Just refer to the source table of each column in the select clause, here if you need 2 joins to the same table give these an **alias** and refer to the columns using that alias.

```
SELECT incident.`number`
    , caller.first_name as caller_name
    , creator.first_name AS createdby
FROM ITSM.incident
JOIN ITSM.`user` AS caller ON incident.id_caller = caller.sys_id
JOIN ITSM.`user` AS creator ON incident.id_created_by = creator.sys_id
```

Nb. I'm assuming your join logic is correct

Comment: nah. this query returns by id_caller - the user who call this incident. im added a new sreens for my topic to describe better

Comment: tried to answer on a phone - that didn't work  well - so the answer is changed now